# Return Type of -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: ios, objective-c

When developing for iOS, the first entry point for your app is the `-[AppDelegate  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`. The return type of this method is a `BOOL`. By default, the return type of this method is `YES`. Here is the code automatically generated by Xcode.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

As you can see, Xcode puts in the return statement for you, with the value of `YES`. When I change the value of the return statement to `NO`, and don't change anything else, **nothing happens**. The app doesn't quit or show any unusual behavior. This begs the question, **what is the purpose of the method returning a BOOL, when the returned value doesn't matter?** If the value returned doesn't matter, why doesn't the method just return void?
Note: Some of my expectations after changing the return to `NO` were either

- Application doesn't launch because it doesn't receive "permission" (`NO` is returned)
- Either compiler generates warning, or error is raised at runtime.
  Why is it the case that **neither of these things happen?**

Comment: Read all of the documentation for the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. The return value is explained there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If there is a URL in `launchOptions` and you return `NO`, then the operating system will know that you cannot open the provided URL for some reason.

It's not used for anything else. Since usually there is no URL in `launchOptions` it usually doesn't matter what you return.

So just return `YES`. You can read more in the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).