# What happens if we return NO in didFinishLaunching in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

What happens if I return **No** rather then **Yes** in >

`(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

I have tried both ways: returned **Yes** and **No** but didn't get any change in app launching.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038694/return-type-of-applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions

Comment: Read all of the documentation for the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. The return value is explained there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check  `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

**Return Value**

NO if the app cannot handle the URL resource, otherwise return YES. The return value is ignored if the app is launched as a result of a remote notification.