# how can I integrate facebook login to my ios app when I already have google sign in in appDelegate.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm writing an app and I want to let users to log in to it with either google or facebook accounts. I currently already implemented the google solution and now I want to include facebook, but I'm struggling with one thing.

In the fb sign in tutorial the author asks to prepare the method in `AppDelegate.swift` class:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

My problem is that I already have the function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` implemented with google sign in logic:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 var configureError: NSError?
 GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
 assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

 if let currentUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser {
     print("user is signed in as "+GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID)

     let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

     if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
     window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
     }
  } else {
            print("user is NOT signed in")
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as? ViewController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        }
   return true
}
```

So what now? is there any way of connecting/merging those two methods together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add both facebook and google codes in the same function.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    // Google sign in code
    // ...

    return true
}
```

The return value (true/false) does not really matter. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038694/return-type-of-applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions) for explanation.